# Unlocked bootloader, encryption

Tags: security, encryption, bootloader

- galaxy nexus
- unlocked bootloader
- no adb enabled
- rooted
- device encryption on with 10+ characters (Cryptfs Password - Google play)
- PIN screen lock with 6 characters

Am I safe if someone wants to extract data from my phone with phone on and off ?
what should I do improve ? Did I miss anything ?

Comment: Your phone is as only as safe *provided* you do not lose it! Also, recommended to install a firewall, such as [AFWall+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dev.ukanth.ufirewall&hl=en) and appropriately block certain apps. Other than that.

Comment: Thanks, I think I am already pretty safe on software thanks  to openpdroid and DroidWall. Thing I really worried was thieves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The combination of encryption, PIN lock, and having ADB turned off should protect your data pretty well.  It could still be compromised if someone finds a security flaw that can be exploited through the network or the MTP USB connection, but that risk exists in any case.

However, with your bootloader unlocked, someone could take your phone, flash a malicious ROM that contains keystroke loggers or something, and then return the phone to you and wait for you to type your PIN or decryption password.  It'd be better to keep the bootloader locked whenever you don't actually need to flash things via fastboot.

You can use [BootUnlocker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.segv11.bootunlocker) to lock and unlock the bootloader from within the running Android system.  Unlike `fastboot oem unlock`, this doesn't wipe your data when you unlock.